# How can I load WebView in custom popup window in android?

Tags: android, xml, webview

I have Create popup.xml and I want to load my webpage in WebView from assets folder.
Here is my popup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/popup"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/pp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Here is my activity file
How to load my webpage in webview with popup window?
Is there any solution?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Point p;
    public int a, b, c, d;
    ImageButton au, gc, cert, busa;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        au = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.au);
        gc = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.gc);
        cert = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cert);
        busa = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.busa);

        au.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (p != null) {
                    showPopup(MainActivity.this, p);

                }

            }
        });
    }

    // Get the x and y position after the button is draw on screen
    // (It's important to note that we can't get the position in the onCreate(),
    // because at that stage most probably the view isn't drawn yet, so it will
    // return (0, 0))
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

        int[] location = new int[2];

        // Get the x, y location and store it in the location[] array
        // location[0] = x, location[1] = y.

        // Initialize the Point with x, and y positions
        p = new Point();
        p.x = location[0];
        p.y = location[1];
    }

    // The method that displays the popup.
    private void showPopup(final Activity context, Point p) {
        int popupWidth = 720;
        int popupHeight = 380;

        // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
        LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context
                .findViewById(R.id.popup);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, viewGroup);

        // Creating the PopupWindow
        final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
        popup.setContentView(layout);
        popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
        popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
        popup.setFocusable(true);

        // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the right, and a bit down,
        // relative to button's position.
        int OFFSET_X = 130;
        int OFFSET_Y = 100;
        // Clear the default translucent background
        // popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

        // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
        popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x + OFFSET_X, p.y
                + OFFSET_Y);

        // Getting a reference to Close button, and close the popup when
        // clicked.

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Webview](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

```
webview1.loadURL("the url goes here");
```